# Separating GET and POST fields in an ASP.MVC view model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Let's assume we have a view model for the view which contains single drop down list. The view model should have two fields:

- List for drop down list
- Selected item

Is it reasonable to distinguish between them, for instance by grouping them as follows:

```
public class ExampleVM
{
    #region GET

    public List<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region POST

    public int? SelectedItem { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

Or maybe there's another way of distinguishing between those fields?

Comment: You're thinking too much into it. Just use the VM for what it is. Prefix the Property names, separate with regions. The most important thing is to be consistent with your team.

Answer (score 5):

In theory these are separate models. One is for view rendering (called **view model**), another is for input handling (called **input model**). If you would like to, you can even define different classes for each. It's just that in practice these models usually resemble each other in so many ways, that it is redundant to keep two very similar model classes.

Consider a case of a single textbox form. The view model is one string which represents current value of the textbox. The input model is a single string with the very same name, which represents user's input, if any. So while modelling this you can create two classes with single string properties, or you can use one class for both.

Your case with dropdown *seems* different because you need two properties, one for rendering list and one for posted selected item. But it only seems so. As soon as you need user not only to enter a new value but also to update existing one, you'll find that you use selected value property for view (GET section in your code) as well. So reuse again.

For a deeper explanation about ASP.NET MVC models, check out [this article](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/the-three-models-of-asp.net-mvc-apps/) by Dino Esposito.

Bottom line: yes, your distinction is reasonable, but some might consider it impractical or excess.